# launching a uri from my app in half screen mode C# windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, uri, windows-8.1

I'm trying to launch a uri from my windows 8.1 app but can't get it to launch in UseHalf mode
I researched and found that it should be done like this

```
       LauncherOptions lo = new LauncherOptions();
       lo.DesiredRemainingView = ViewSizePreference.UseHalf;
       lo.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
       await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com"),lo);
```

but it keeps launching the web browser in full screen 
I read that the launch depends on many variables and it is not insured that these settings will be applied

my question is there a way to insure that my app and the browser will open side by side in half screen mode?

Comment: Please check an answer or add more help to us

Answer (score 0):

It have to work:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com");
LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions
{
    DesiredRemainingView = ViewSizePreference.UseHalf
};

await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);
```

If not, please try this long code:

```
ApplicationView currentAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();  

CoreApplicationView newCoreAppView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();  

newCoreAppView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(  
  CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,  
  async () =>  
  {  
    // This executes on the new dispatcher so I assume that Window.Current and so on  
    // reflects the new Window associated with that dispatcher rather than the original  
    // dispatcher.  
    Window newWindow = Window.Current;  
    ApplicationView newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();  


    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(  
      newAppView.Id,  
      ViewSizePreference.UseHalf,  
      currentAppView.Id,  
      ViewSizePreference.UseHalf);  
  });
```

from [Here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/10/15/windows-8-1-preview-multiple-windows.aspx).

Comment: nop for some reason it doesn't work when I call this code from my app it goes away completely and the browser opens full size

Comment: well the second way does open two windows side by side but I'm not finding a way to set the second window to show a uri in browser

Answer (score 0):

Well after consulting the msdn developers forum  it turns out this is the only way to do it
and there is no way for an app to force this kind of behavior the result of this code depends on the setting of the browser and many other variables